# A question on Staccato in the end of a slur (piano playing)

Tags: piano, classical-music, classical-period, staccato

[image]

A staccato note in the end of a slur( 1)

A normal staccato note(2)

**question**
Do I play the (1) the same as (2)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  The slur just indicates that the note should touch the preceding note, but it's still played on time and ended according to the staccato dot.

Basically, a slur does not change the last note it reaches but only the notes before it.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to play "Portato" .Portato is also known as articulated legato (Blood 2012).It is a bowing technique for stringed instruments (Anon. 2001), in which successive notes are gently re-articulated while being joined under a single continuing bow stroke. It achieves a kind of pulsation or undulation, rather than separating the notes. It has been notated in various ways. One early 19th century writer, Pierre Baillot (L’art du violon, Paris, 1834), gives two alternatives: a wavy line, and dots under a slur. Later in the century a third method became common: placing "legato" dashes (tenuto) under a slur (Wall 2001a). The notation with dots under slurs is ambiguous, because it is also used for very different bowings, including staccato and flying spiccato (Walls 2001a; Walls 2001b).

Currently, mezzo-staccato is sometimes indicated in words, by "mezzo-staccato" or "non-legato"; or can be shown by three graphic forms:

a slur that encompasses a phrase of staccato notes (the most common), or
a tenuto above a staccato mark (very often), or
a slur that encompasses a phrase of tenuto notes (less common) (Tsai 2008).
Portato is defined by some authorities as "the same as portamento" (Kennedy 1994).

Comment: This answer appears to be about violin technique, not piano. Also, if the whole answer is apparently a quote cut-and-pasted from somewhere, you should give a reference to the original source.

Comment: Portato is more to do with what happens DURING a slur, rather than the last note. All the player does in the quoted piece is cut the last note short.